# API modularization in Restlet

Tags: api, restlet, modularization

I have developed a web application based on Restlet API. As I am adding more features over time, I need sometimes to reuse similar group of REST API under different endpoints, which provides slightly different context of execution (like switching different instances of databases with same schema). I like to refactor my code to make the API reusable and reuse them at different endpoints. My initial thinking was to design an Application for each reusable API and attach them on the router:

```
router.attach("/context1",APIApplication.class)
router.attach("/foo/context2",APIApplication.class)
```

The API should be agnostic of configuration of the REST API. What is the best way to pass context information (for example the instance of database) to the Application API?  Is this approach viable and correct? What are the best practices to reuse REST API in Restlet? Some code samples would be appreciated to illustrate your answer.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have see this basic set-up running using a Component as the top level object, attaching the sub applications to the VirtualHost rather than a router, as per this skeleton sample.

```
public class Component extends org.restlet.Component
{
  public Component() throws Exception
  {
    super();
    // Client protocols
    getClients().add(Protocol.HTTP);

    // Database connection
    final DataSource dataSource = InitialContext.doLookup("java:ds");
    final Configuration configuration = new Configuration(dataSource);

    final VirtualHost host = getDefaultHost();

    // Portal modules
    host.attach("/path1", new FirstApplication());
    host.attach("/path2", new SecondApplication(configuration));
    host.attach("/path3", new ThirdApplication());
    host.attachDefault(new DefaultApplication(configuration));
  }
}
```

We used a custom Configuration object basically a pojo to pass any common config information where required, and used this to construct the Applications, we used separate 'default' Contexts for each Application.

This was coded originally against restlet 1.1.x and has been upgraded to 2.1.x via 2.0.x, and although it works and is reasonably neat there may possibly be an even better way to do it in either versions 2.1.x or 2.2.x.